# A function that takes an array of strings and return a filtered array containing the same element but with the other array elements removed

Tags: python, arrays

```
geese = ["African", "Roman Tufted", "Toulouse", "Pilgrim", "Steinbacher"]
birds = ["Mallard", "Hook Bill", "African", "Crested", "Pilgrim", "Toulouse", "Blue Swedish"]
def goose_filter(birds):
   for i in birds:
      if i in geese:
          birds.remove(i)
print(goose_filter)
```

I just started learning python, so I'm using codewars.com to practice the fundamentals, but I'm stuck with challenge. So basically they want me to remove any string in birds that is similar to the strings in geese. Also how do I print a function, the print() method doesn't work.

Comment: Two things. First, You are passing a function object to print. Second, you are modifying a list while iterating over it.

Comment: (1) You work with lists here, not arrays. (2) Did the task really mention "similar" strings or equal strings (be precise)? (3) Don't modify a list while you iterate over it with a for-loop, create a new list with the items to keep instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
geese = ["African", "Roman Tufted", "Toulouse", "Pilgrim", "Steinbacher"]
birds = ["Mallard", "Hook Bill", "African", "Crested", "Pilgrim", "Toulouse", "Blue Swedish"]
def goose_filter(birds,geese):
   for i in birds:
      if i in geese:
          birds.remove(i)
   return birds
print(goose_filter(birds,geese)) #['Mallard', 'Hook Bill', 'Crested', 'Toulouse', 'Blue Swedish']
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).